# The etymology of Sanskrit jāla 'web'

Tags: etymology, sanskrit

I am looking for an etymology on the Sanskrit word jāla 'web'. What is the origin of it? I am trying to find a parallel in other Indo-European languages but no luck so far.

Comment: I vote to leave it open (at least for the moment).

Comment: same here as jknappen.

Comment: Have you looked in Mayrhofer's etymological dictionary?

Comment: @fdb: Not yet, but I will. I have at least confirmed the root exists in Iranic languages as well.

Comment: Sanskrit dictionaries derive it from root _jala_ "to cover; to be sharp; to be wealthy". One dictionary says "cf. Latin galea".

Comment: @Midas What are the assumed Iranian cognates you have found?

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev its been 4 years since I posted this, sonI don’t really remember. In any case your answer was the right one for the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm posting this not as a definitve answer, but in the hope that this information can stimulate some further thought and search.)

### StarLing database

In the [Starling](http://starling.rinet.ru/babel.php?lan=en) database (the Indo-European part was compiled by Sergei Nikolayev), it is supposed to be related to the Indo-European root [`*ger` "to weave"](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fie%2fpiet&text_number=++1681&root=config):

```
Proto-IE: *ger-

Meaning: to weave

Old Indian: guṇá- m. `a single thread or strand of a cord or twine, string, rope';
jaṭā f. `hair twisted together; fibrous root';
jāla- n. `net, snare, cob-web, any woven texture';
gala- `reed, rope of reed (L.)';
gárta- m. `high seat, throne'

Baltic: *geran̂k=, *garan̂k= (2); *gerg=, *gerk=

Germanic: *kar-m-a- m.

Russ. meaning: плести

References: WP I 593 f
```

However, the details of this derivation is unclear to me.

(I can suppose deriving it from a protoform like `*gērT-` [through Indo-Iranian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Iranian_language#Historical_phonology) palatalization before *ē*, merger of non-high vowels, and some unclear consonant cluster development into *l*; this protoform has a [long ablaut grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut#Ablaut_grades) (under which rule?) and some unclear consonant *T*. But my knowledge in this field is limited; I'm just refering to some well-known historical phonetic processes.

The development like `*rt, *rd, *ry > l` is typical for the history of some Iranian languages, though I lack the knowledge concerning similar processes in Old Indian or Prakrits.)

#### Additional, possibly relevant entries from Pokorny's dictionary

If we follow the reference to the Pokorny's dictionary (as saved in the StarLing database), there are a lot of suggested related forms (with extensions), though Old Indian *jāla-* is not among them. (So, it must be the idea of the authors of the Starling database.)

An extract from [WP I 593 f (Root: ger-3)](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fie%2fpokorny&text_number=+576&root=config) in Pokorny's dictionary (I'm listing only the dental extensions, since they seem to be closest to the Old Indian form in question *jāla-*):

```
Number: 576

Root: ger-3

English meaning: to turn, wind

German meaning: `drehen, winden'

Material: A. Ai. guṇá-ḥ (*gr̥-nó-s) `der einzelne Faden einer Schnur, Schnur, Strick;
mal' (dvi-, tri-guṇa- eigentlich `aus zwei, drei Fäden bestehend');
gárta-ḥ `Wagensitz des Streitwagens' (`*aus Ruten geflochtener Sitz, Wagenkorb'),
vgl. mit Formans -mo- anord. karmr `Brustwehr',
schwed. karm `Rückenlehne aus Flechtwerk, Wagenkorb' (*gor-mo-s `Flechtwerk').

    1. Gutturalerweiterungen:

...

    2. Dentalerweiterungen:

    a. gr-et(h)-: ags. cradol m. `Wiege' (*kradula- `geflochtenes'), ahd. kratto `Korb' (*kraddan-), krezzo, mhd. krezze, nhd. Krätze `Tragkorb' (*krattian).

    b. Nasaliert:

    Ai. granth-, grathnā́mi, Fut. granthiṣyāmi `winden, knüpfen, einen Knoten binden', Partiz. grathitá- `gewunden, knotig, zusammengeballt', granthí-ḥ m. `Knoten, Gelenk, Anschwellung', grantha-ḥ `Knoten', grathín- `ränkevoll', grathila- `verrückt'; aber ghatā- `Menge, Schar' ist nichtidg. (Kuiper Proto-Munda 55 f.).

    c. ger-d, gr-ed-, nasaliert grend-:

    Air. grinne (*grend-n-i̯o-) `Bündel, Reisbündel, fascis';

    anord. kartr, ags. cræt m. `Wagen' (wohl `geflochtener Wagenkorb'), wohl auch anord. kart-nagl `mißgestalteter Nagel', norw. kart m. `unreife Frucht, Knorren', ostfries. kret `verschrumpfte Frucht', mhd. krenze `Korb', ahd. kranz, nhd. Kranz;

    lit. grandìs (reduktionsstufig grundis) `Armband, Eisenring, Reif des Rades, runder Käsekuchen', apr. grandis `der Grindelring am Pflug, der den Pflugbaum mit dem Vordergestell verbindet', lett. grùods `stark gedreht, drall';

    poln. grędać się `sich drehen'.

    3. Labialerweiterungen:

...

    4. s-Erweiterung *gre-s-, nur germ.: ...

    B. Wurzelform gr-eu-; grū̆-mo- `Zusammengekratztes':

...

References: WP. I 593 ff., WH. 623, Trautmann 94 f., 97, 99 f.

Pages: 385-390
```

It is linked to one more entry in the IE database of Starling, namely [`*grent- (-th-), -d-` "to plait, to braid, to bind, to twist"](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fie%2fpiet&text_number=+289&root=config):

```
Proto-IE: *grent- (-th-), -d-

Meaning: to plait, to braid, to bind, to twist

Old Indian: grathnā́ti, f. granthiṣyati `to fasten, tie or string together',
grantha- m., granthí- m. `knot'

Old Greek: gróntho-s m. `geballte Faust'

Slavic: *grǭdātī sę̄ (Pol dial. grędać się `sich drehen')

Baltic: *grañd-i- c., *grund-i- m., *grañd-a- adj.

  Proto-Baltic: *grañd-i- c., *grund-i- m., *grañd-a- adj.

  Lithuanian: grandì-s 'Ring einer Kette, Kettenglied, Armband', ostlit. grundi-s

  Lettish: grùods 'drall, stark gedreht, stramm'

  Old Prussian: grandis (überl. graudis) 'Rincke' ('Grindelring am Pfluge, der den Pflugbaum mit dem Vordergestell verbindet') Voc. 251

Germanic: *krant-a- m., *krant-iōn- f.; *krad-Vl-a- m., *kradd=, *kratt=

  Proto-Germanic: *kranta-z, *krantiōn; *kradVla-z, *kradd=, *kratt=

  Meaning: cradle, basket

  Old English: cradol m. `Wiege'

  English: cradle

  Old High German: kranz `schmückende Kopfbinde, Krone' (11.Jh.);
  kratto `Korb', krezzo

  Middle High German: kranz st. m. 'kranz';
  krɛnze, krinze, krɛtze wk. f., m. 'tragkorb';
  { krazze `Korb' }

  German: Kranz m.;
  { Krätze `Korb' }

Celtic: OIr grinne `Bündel, Reisbündel, fascis'

Russ. meaning: плести, вязать, скручивать

References: WP I 590 f
```

### Pali Text Society's Pali-English dictionary

PED ([Pali Text Society, London. The Pali Text Society's Pali-English dictionary. Chipstead, 1921-1925. With the "Additions and Corrections" applied.](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/pali/)) has the following concerning the etymology in the [jāla](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=J%C4%81la&searchhws=yes) entry. It points to analoguous l:ṭ alternations in other words. Also note that it says that this word can be traced to Vedic, i.e., old.

```
1) Jāla (p. 283) Jāla Jāla1 (nt.)
[Vedic jāla, prob. from jaṭ to plait, make a tangle cp. jaṭita & jaṭā;
on l:ṭ cp. phulla: sphuṭa; cāru: cāṭu; cela: ceṭa]
a net; netting, entanglement (lit. or fig.): snare, deceptíon (=māyā).
```

Concering the etymology of *jaṭ* "to plait, make a tangle", which it refers to (and which is also mentioned in the entry for `*ger` in the StarLing database), there is not much additional interesting information:

[jaṭā](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=Ja%E1%B9%AD%C4%81&searchhws=yes):

```
1) Jaṭā (p. 277) Jaṭā Jaṭā (f.) [B.Sk. jatā]
tangle, braid, plaiting, esp. (a) the matted hair as worn by ascetics (see jatila)
```

[jaṭita](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=Ja%E1%B9%ADita&searchhws=yes):

```
1) Jaṭita (p. 277) Jaṭita Jaṭita [pp. of jaṭ, to which also jaṭā; Dhtp 95: sanghāte]
entangled
```